# How to know if MS Windows has alive red or internet connection?

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [check whether internet connection is available with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085045/check-whether-internet-connection-is-available-with-c-sharp)

I just want to know which methods we have to use to detect programmatically (C#) if MS Windows  has alive Internet/red connection or doesn't.

Is it possible to do?

Thank you!

For example: if I put down WIFI how I can know that there is any connection?

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916243/detect-when-network-cable-unplugged

Comment: Also I found this answer which is also good!


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843810/fastest-way-to-test-internet-connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [Ping class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping.aspx)

```
       Ping pingSender = new Ping ();
        PingOptions options = new PingOptions ();

        // Use the default Ttl value which is 128,
        // but change the fragmentation behavior.
        options.DontFragment = true;

        // Create a buffer of 32 bytes of data to be transmitted.
        string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes (data);
        int timeout = 120;
        PingReply reply = pingSender.Send ("www.google.com", timeout, buffer, options);
        if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Address: {0}", reply.Address.ToString ());
            Console.WriteLine ("RoundTrip time: {0}", reply.RoundtripTime);
            Console.WriteLine ("Time to live: {0}", reply.Options.Ttl);
            Console.WriteLine ("Don't fragment: {0}", reply.Options.DontFragment);
            Console.WriteLine ("Buffer size: {0}", reply.Buffer.Length);
        }
```

Comment: ICMP ping is blocked off by some routers/configurations.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following method to check for connectivity:

```
public bool CheckForInternetConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            using (var stream = client.OpenRead("http://www.google.com"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You Have connectity!");
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No internet connection found.");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The method attempts to load Google's URL and returns true if it loads, false if it does not.

Comment: Do you think that Ping approach is faster? or?

Comment: No idea on raw speed - this method returns results that are adequate for my purposes.

Comment: all depends on how big the website you are reading is

Comment: @MicahArmantrout In fact I have to check if WebServices are alive.

Comment: why not just attempt to connect and wrap in a try catch ?