# How can i detect if my lan connection is down/up in C++

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2008

I have a pc with 2 lan ports, will be using one of them for communication purpose, wondering if there is a way which my software can detect if the lan connection is up/down and display the status on my software gui. langauge is C++.

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916243/detect-when-network-cable-unplugged

Answer (score 0):

In Qt `QNetworkInterface::flags()` returns a set of flags describing the interface. On of them is `QNetworkInterface::IsUp`. You might also check for `QNetworkInterface::IsLoopBack`

Comment: I've tried IsUp and IsActive flags, they always exist not depending on cable plugged/unplugged.

Comment: Strange, on my work machine (Windows 7) both `::isUp` and `::isActive` flags go down when a network cable is unplugged. Machine itself has to detect presence of a cable. Just for the sake of it - check `QNetworkInterface::humanReadableName()` if you are looking at correct interface - I, for example, have 9, 2 of which are "real".

Comment: Hi friendzis,
I'm using linux. On win7 this might work, but not on linux. There's a number of features in qt, that wont work on linux, but they work on windows...

Comment: IIRC on linux simple network managers e.g. `netctl` do not install hooks to bring iface down when cable is disconnected. I'll check that