# How do I detect when a user disconnects from the network?

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detect When Network Cable Unplugged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916243/detect-when-network-cable-unplugged)

I would need some help to check if somebody disconnected. At the moment my code says that somebody disconnected every time I connect to it. I tried to use send() to check if they are still "alive" but I'm not sure if I did it right.

```
#pragma comment (lib,"Ws2_32.lib")

#include <iostream>
#include <WinSock2.h>

using namespace std;

#pragma region shittyvars

int countcons = 0, connections[100];
char *dead = new char;
int error;
WSAData netinfo;
int mySocket;
HANDLE acceptth, discth;

#pragma endregion

void AcceptThread( int* a)
{
int clientSocket;
while ( (clientSocket = accept(mySocket,0,0))!=SOCKET_ERROR) 
   connections[countcons++]=clientSocket;
}
void DissconectThread(int*b)
{
for(;;)
  for(int i=0;i<countcons;i++)
   {
       error = send(connections[i],dead,4,0);
 error = WSAGetLastError();
       if(error != 0 )
       {
           closesocket(connections[i]);
           for(int j=i+1 ; j<countcons ;j++)
               connections[j-1]=connections[j];
           countcons--;
           cout<<"\nSomebody disconnected\n";
       }
   }
}

int main() {
#pragma region InitConnection
    error = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &netinfo);

    if (error == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        cout << "Error:Starting socket failed";
        return 1;
    }

    mySocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (mySocket == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        cout << "Error:Socket failed to initialize!";
        return 1;
    }
    cout << "Works!";

    struct sockaddr_in server; // network socket struct

    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(7654);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; // Let's us accept any connection

    error = bind(mySocket, (sockaddr*) &server, sizeof(server));

    if (error == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        cout << "Error:Failed to bind socket";
        return 1;
    }

    error = listen(mySocket, 100);

    if (error == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        cout << "Error:The socket is deaf";
        return 1;
    }

#pragma endregion

    acceptth = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) AcceptThread,
            &server, 0, (LPDWORD) &acceptth);
    discth = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) DissconectThread,
            &server, 0, (LPDWORD) &discth);
    getchar();
    closesocket(mySocket);
    WSACleanup();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: The title says `smb`, but I don't see Server Message Block protocol being used here.  Was that a mistake in the title?

Comment: First as far as i know smb is a classic english abbreviation for somebody and second the connections array is initialized since is a global array all of it's values are initialisez with 0 as far as i know.

Comment: Do not use abbreviations for real words. There is no such thing. We expect as clear and proper language as possible - we're all about quality. =)

Comment: ok sorry about that this is kinda one of my first questions here

Comment: No worries, that's why I'm letting you know. There'll be other things for you to learn as you ask more and more questions, and hopefully even answer some!

Comment: By the way, the error checking inside the loop in the acceptor thread will never be done. When `accept` returns `SOCKET_ERROR` the loop will be broken, and no more statements inside the body of the loop will be executed.

Comment: Also, when you send your "ping", you send four or eight bytes (`sizeof` of a pointer returns the size of the pointer, not the size of what it points to).

Comment: Thirdly, the usual way to check for disconnects is to try and _receive_ from the socket. A socket is marked as readable when it has been disconnected. Use e.g. [`select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to check for if a socket is readable.

Comment: Fourhtly, you don't actually check _what_ error you get from the `send` call. It could be anything. Oh and one last thing: When you get an error and want to close the socket, you should actually _close_ the socket.

Comment: Iv looked select up before i tryed to use this method but i didn't really get what it does... ( sorry im kinda young and inexperienced ~ same reason why my english is soo bad) Anyway at this moment i would like to get this method working and afterwards i might try to use the select() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the error you get when the `send` fails... it might point you in the right direction (use `WSAGetLastError()` on Windows).  Incidentally, your `DissconectThread` will just spin and chew CPU until there's a connection, then it will jam out data until it blocks on one connection with a full send buffer... probably not what you intended.

Comment: I edited the code with what i got last ( those errors are when the connections time out and when it cant reach or smt like that ) now it does not show that somebody dissconected when somebody connects but it doesnt show that somebody dissconects when they do .

Comment: Also i tryed to add a error = WSAGetLastError() before the if but it still does not work

Comment: `send` returns the number of bytes sent, not the error code.  `WSAGetLastError()` can't *not* work, it *must* return something.  What did it return?

Comment: 10054(Connection reset by peer.) the first connection and then it went to 10053 (Software caused connection abort.) still not sure what to check cuz when somebody disconnects it keeps giving the same one

Comment: yeah managed to do it thnx a lot ( the problem was that i had to check if the think was != 0 ( it returns 0 if there is a connection ) thnx a lot guys :D ur great :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the return values of `read()` and `write()` calls on your sockets (same for `recv()` and `send()`).

- For graceful connection termination on the other side you'll get `0` from `read()`,
- For abrupt disconnections you'll get `-1` from `write()` and `WSAECONNRESET` from [`WSAGetLastError()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741580%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
- Check all other error codes on getting `-1` from [`send()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740149%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`recv()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), ignore things like `WSAEINTR`, close the socket on all others.

It would be much better to incorporate some regular on-idle ***heartbeat*** into your ***application-level protocol*** instead of pounding your system from a dedicated thread like you have now.