# Is there any Windows Message for detecting network cable is plugged or unplugged?

Tags: windows, notify, nic

I made some MFC program using multiple Network Interface Cables.
This program show current usable NICs.

I just want how i can get notify when the network cable is plugged or unplugged.

It must be run on windows XP.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/q/2916243/2065121

Comment: Yes, i know i can detect cable status for looping, but i am finding event. Can i register this kind of event for plugged and unplugged on XP?